# Beautifulsoup findall() can't find all targets

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, findall

I want to crawl some pictures in Redfin website, but it seems that FindAll() method can't find all the image url whose parent class is ImageCard.

Here's the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

def make_soup(url):
 headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.6) Gecko/20091201 Firefox/3.5.6'}
 req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=headers)
 thepage = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
 soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
 return soupdata

 soup = make_soup("https://www.redfin.com/CA/San-Diego/5747-Adobe-Falls-Rd-92120/unit-A/home/5437025")

 imgcards = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'ImageCard'})
 for imgcard in imgcards:
 img = imgcard.findAll('img')
 print(img['src'])
```

[I want to download all the images in this slide on the web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0Mn0.jpg)

The elements tree is :
[elements tree of webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbVL4.png)

I can just find the first image's div of the slide. Hope someone can figure it out! Thanks!!

Comment: sidenote: use `find_all()` instead of `findAll()`: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names

Answer (score 1):

The html does not include the links to these extra photos. That is why you can't find it. They are being created with javascript and your program does not process javascript.

However, if you look carefully, you will find this:

`<meta content="http://media.cdn-redfin.com/photo/48/bigphoto/983/160048983_0.jpg" name="twitter:image:src">`

That is an alt url for the first picture.

The url to the 2nd picture is:

`https://ssl.cdn-redfin.com/photo/48/bigphoto/983/160048983_1_0.jpg`

url to 3rd:

`https://ssl.cdn-redfin.com/photo/48/bigphoto/983/160048983_2_0.jpg`

You could leverage this to get what you want (you can guess the url to the extra pictures based on the first).

Comment: Thank you so much! But how can I catch content created by javascript? I also need some other information in this page, but it seems that they are all created by javascript.

Comment: I'm no expert, but one way might be to use some kind of browser with a webdriver like https://realpython.com/blog/python/headless-selenium-testing-with-python-and-phantomjs/ . It will process the javascript then you scrape from it.

Comment: you can try `mechanize` package  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/